# PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments out of memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdfbox

I have a list of documents in byte[] format :

```
List<byte[]> documents; // got from a call to another API
```

I tried to merge documents in the list above:

```
PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
List<byte[]> documents = new ArrayList<>();
for (byte[] document : documents) {
    pdfMerger.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(document));
}
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pdfMerger.setDestinationStream(os);
try {
    pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error during document merge.", e);
}
```

the application crashes and reboots when executing this line :

```
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
```

I think that it caused by a lack of memory allocated in jvm (=> I dont have a possibility to setup more memory because I don't have the admin rights). There are 50 documents to merge (approximately 50mb, maybe more).

so do you have any way to fix it ?

thanks

Comment: So you want to do everything in memory, and wonder about out of memory? MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly should be self explaining, and giving PDFs as blobs in memory is a terrible idea.

Comment: *"I think that it caused by a lack of memory allocated in jvm"* - you mean you have not verified?

Comment: 9ilsdx 9rvj 0lo: I also think it's not a good idea to do this directly in memory, that's why I'm looking for a better solution (store directly on the hard drive, or something like that)

Comment: Mkl: i did a verification : I have monitored server memory usage while the code is executing, and the application is taking a lot of memory compared to other applications on the server. I stopped 5 applications that were running on the server, I restarted my code and it worked

Comment: Did you try a different call for `MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly()`?

Comment: Tilman Hausherr :  I tried MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly() and MemoryUsageSetting.setupMixed(-1, -1) but always the same problem

Comment: According to the javadoc "if -1 this is the same as MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly()". Try `MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly()`.

Comment: I have also tried MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly() => same problem